# How to know row index of a DataList (table)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datalist

I have a Datalist with differet images and descriptions...  i wish click an image and through javascript know index of the row selected (to make a paging pictures).

i have this code, but not works... it always returns 1 in the variable "current page".

MY ASP.NET CODE

```
      <HeaderTemplate>
          <table style="width: 100%;">
             <tr>
                 <th style="width: 25%"></th>
                  <th style="width: 45%">
                     <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblLegenda" Text="legenda" />
                   </th>
                   <th style="width: 10%;"></th>
              </tr>
       </HeaderTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
               <tr>
                   <td style="padding: 5px">
                        <asp:Image ID="img_gall" onclick="LoadDiv(this.src, this)" Style="cursor: pointer;" runat="server" Width="70px"  ImageUrl='imageurl' />
                   </td>
                   <td>
                       <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMultimediaDesciprion" Text='description' />
                   </td>
                    <td class="icons">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="delete_image" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete.png" runat="server" CommandName='<%# Eval("ID") %>'  OnClick="delete_image" />
                    </td>
              </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>
       <AlternatingItemTemplate>
               <tr class="colored">
                    <td style="padding: 5px">
                         <asp:Image ID="img_gall" onclick="LoadDiv(this.src, this)"  runat="server"   ImageUrl='imageurl' /></td>
                     <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMultimediaDesciprion" Text='description' />
                      </td>
                     <td class="icons">
                         <asp:ImageButton ID="delete_image" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete.png" runat="server" CommandName='<%# Eval("ID") %>'  OnClick="delete_image"  />
                     </td>
                  </tr>
             </AlternatingItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
 var CurrentPage = 1;
        function GetImageIndex(obj) {
            while (obj.parentNode.tagName != "TD")
                obj = obj.parentNode;
            var td = obj.parentNode;
            var tr = td.parentNode;

            if (td.rowIndex % 2 == 0) {
                return td.cellIndex + tr.rowIndex;
            }
            else {
                return td.cellIndex + (tr.rowIndex * 2);
            }
        }
        function LoadDiv(url, lnk) {

            CurrentPage = GetImageIndex(lnk.parentNode) + 1;

}
```

anyome can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You duplicated the "parentNode", change

```
GetImageIndex(lnk.parentNode)
```

To

```
GetImageIndex(lnk)
```

Comment: yes, it works...
but i have another problem.

it returns the strange ids... it returns the ids (ie)  4,5,9 ...and the total number of elements is 3, I'm not able to do pagination. 

I thought he would return 1,2,3 (or 0, 1.2) ... in this case for three elements ...

you can help me?

Comment: @AnaMariaMendes Please post the generated html

Answer (score 0):

//OnItemCommand="dlstnewproducts_ItemCommand" use this in your datalist in source.

//And for image give CommandName="Edit"

protected void Datalist_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
                {
                    string Key = Datalist.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString();
                    //Response.Redirect("ViewProduct1.aspx?UserId="+Key);
                }
               else 
                {
                  Response.redirect(login.aspx);
                }

And in the key you will get the index